# Price = 0 not showing Magento

Tags: magento

So when a downloadable product price is set to 0, the price is not showing on the product page. Where´s an example http://piccystock.com/seagull-eating-bread.html

would like to display 0€ just as the other prices

Comment: Which version of Magento are you running?

Comment: any hints on this one?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/catalog/product/links.phtml:

89
 optionsPrice.displayZeroPrice = false;

to  optionsPrice.displayZeroPrice = true;

Comment: I found that possibility before. After I implement it however, on checkout, 2 products appear automatically, both the free product and another one. So I guess it´s not the way or something missing.